# Filter Umbraco dynamic variable by Alias in foreach

Tags: c#, linq, razor, umbraco

I am trying to filter a dynamic variable by the Alias and would like to know if this is possible as when I write a lamba expression eg

`foreach (var item in node.Children.Where(x => x.NodeTypeAlias != "ContentContainer"))`

This results in an error - use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delagate or an expression tree type..

Please can someone help me on this.

```
  if (sub.NodeTypeAlias == "MenuExternalLink")
        {
            UrlPickerState urlPicker = UrlPickerState.Deserialize(sub.GetPropertyValue("LinkURL"));
            subUrl = urlPicker.Url;
            subTarget = urlPicker.NewWindow ? "_blank" : "";


            //get root home page node
            var homePage = CurrentModel.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();
            //get the node under the homepage where the node name matches the redirect (MenuExternalLink) node name
            var menuNode = homePage.Children.Where(x => x.NodeTypeAlias == "NormalTextPage" && x.Name.Contains(sub.Name) && x.GetPropertyValue("umbracoNaviHide") != "1");
            //get the nodes under menuNode

            foreach (var q in menuNode)
            {
                //we have the id of the node so get the child nodes based on that id
                var node = Library.NodeById(q.Id);

                foreach (var item in node.Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"NormalTextPage\""))
                {

                    <li ><a href="@item.Url" >@item.Name</a></li>

                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: Where is sub coming from?  It's not defined in your code snippet above

Comment: Hi wingyip thanks for your comment and I have edited the code to include sub. I solved it by using -                                                                              foreach (var item in node.Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"NormalTextPage\""))

Comment: Have you tried assigning this piece of code to the variable outside the `foreach` loop: `node.Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"NormalTextPage\"")`? And afterwards use it to iterate through it in `foreach`.